# get localized string in android

Tags: android, localization

I need to get the `phone` and `email` string (the string, not the content of a contact) in it's localized form. How do I get the localized string from android default's contact app or any other way that I can access?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to see if it is defined in `android.R.string`. If it is not there, that means it is not a public string and as such, should not be used by your application.

By the way, you should not make any assumption with respect to the "default contact app" because this is frequently modified by manufacturers (e.g. on Samsung phones).

Comment: I think this make sense. I'll wait for few more days to mark this answer.